# Python memcache flush_all behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, memcached

I'm wondering if anyone can help shed some light on why calling `flush_all()` doesn't seem to update stats. If I create a client, add 1 key, get it, and then `flush_all()` I'd expect a subsequent `get_stats()` to return `0` for `curr_items`, but it doesn't.  Not until a `get()` of the key is performed after the `flush_all()` will `curr_items` be set back to `0`.

Here's an example of what I'm witnessing:

```
import memcache

# Create a client
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)

# Add a key
mc.add('foo', 'bar')
print mc.get('foo')

# Get stats
stats = mc.get_stats()

# There will be 1 current item
print "Initial get_stat(): {}".format(stats[0][1]['curr_items'])

# Flush all
mc.flush_all()

# Get stats again
stats2 = mc.get_stats()

# There shouldn't be any items, but there is 1
print "Second get_stat(): {}".format(stats2[0][1]['curr_items'])

# Get the one key we added before
mc.get('foo')

# Get stats a third time
stats3 = mc.get_stats()

# There shouldn't be any items and now there aren't
print "Third get_stat(): {}".format(stats3[0][1]['curr_items'])
```

Execution results:

```
bar
Initial get_stat(): 1
Second get_stat(): 1
Third get_stat(): 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `flush` operation doesn't actually remove anything from memory, it just marks everything as expired. Expired items aren't actually removed until you try to access them.

Comment: Thanks, @barmar.  Is there a way to forcibly remove them?  In any event, thanks for answering my initial question.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I thought I was noticing that is was taking a long time to flush all the items.  So, I wrote a routine that would execute flush_all(), wait, get stats and check curr_items, and then repeat if curr_items > 0.  The loop would never exit for the reason you mentioned above.  Anyway, it turns out that I was wrong about the delay.  Was thrown a red herring as I was using a GUI to view the keys.  After I'd execute flush_all() I'd refresh the kes and watch them disappear 1 by 1. Thanks again for your help. Executing flush_all() and knowing that the keys will not be GET'able is working for my use case.